# Can I install Linux if in Motherboard spec say only about Windows support?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, drivers, motherboard

I'm starting research components for my new computer which should work with Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10 at the same time. But in the specification motherboard, I saw only Windows 10 64-bit support.

[Something like this](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/Z370M-D3H-rev-10#sp)

In `Operating System` section, only Windows. 
Can I install Ubuntu with this motherboard or motherboards with similar characteristics in `Operating System` section (Without Linux)?

Comment: Almost always. Just do not except vendor to offer help if issue. Some installs with benchmarks: http://openbenchmarking.org/s/gigabyte%20z370  I have an older Gigabyte Z170 and it works well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be 100% sure, buy a computer which is certified to be Ubuntu compatible (https://certification.ubuntu.com).

However, I have not encountered a single computer in my life on which I would not be able to install linux. You can be pretty sure that motherboard will support Ubuntu. The most problems I have had with linux support were various WiFi adapters, where I had to compile kernel modules in order to make them work. I would not give to much attention to what is supported, as I am pretty sure linux will work.